# Cannot add OracleConnection in sql server project type in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, visual-studio, connection

I want to create an Oracle connection in a SQL Server project type in Visual Studio. When I use

```
Using oracle.DataAccess.Client
```

It shows this error:

> Error 1   SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>   Msg 701, Level 17, State 11, Line 1
>   There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.

And if I use

```
Using System.Data.OracleClient
```

Then it shows this error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure OracleConnetion, Line 0
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or
>   aggregate "OracleConnetion":
>   System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Data.OracleClient.OraclePermission, System.Data.OracleClient,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
>   at System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand()
>   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.DemandPermission()
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()
>   at StoredProcedures.Example()

Can anyone help me how to connect with Oracle database please, without having such errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using ODP.net?

Comment: yes, I use odp.net, by adding Oracle.DataAccess as a reference.

Comment: Okay, good...  System.Data.OracleClient is way depricated, so I would focus on the top example.  Can you show more code with the problem area?

Comment: SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
ALTER ASSEMBLY [OracleConnection2]
    FROM 0x4D5A90000300000004000000FFF..................